# Why can't non-POD objects be copied with memcpy?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

According to various sources I've read, the following C++ code invokes undefined behaviour:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void method () {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

...
A *a, *b;
// obtain 2 Instances from somewhere, then...
memcpy (a, b, sizeof(A));
a->method();
```

Why does this cause undefined behaviour? I can see no logical implementation of the language where this would not behave as expected (in the case where both objects have the same run-time type), so why did the language designers choose to make this undefined?

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` does a shallow copy. In the general case, doing a shallow copy is not safe for types that are not trivially-copyable, for example because the type has a copy constructor that needs to do something special.

Of course you can come up with an example where actually a shallow copy using `memcpy` "works" but then the standard would have to list all the cases that are allowed, and that would require knowing all the valid implementation choices and assessing what would work.

Instead  the standard just says you can't do it, which is the right choice IMHO.

Use `memcpy` for copying raw bytes. Use a copy constructor for copying objects. It's a simple, logical rule.

Comment: It may not be *safe* in the general case to do this, but the consequences of doing it should absolutely be knowable if you understand the implementation of the class in question. I still see no reason why having undefined behaviour here is useful for the language designers or implementers.

Comment: It's not useful for implementors, it's UB to stop idiots shooting themselves in the foot. Using `memcpy` to copy a class breaks encapsulation. If the class author defined a copy constructor or other non-trivial special member function then presumably they had a good reason to do so, and copying it by other means might break the class' invariants. If a class is virtual there are things that happen behind the scenes that the compiler does to initialize a class, users should not be creating objects by bypassing that initialization and creating frankenstein objects that didn't get constructed.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the language says "what you want to do breaks the object model of C++, that is not supported".

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is it fine to use memcpy on non-POD type where class/struct performs no dynamic memory allocation & doesn't use handle any resource.Is this program fine & have well defined behaviour?. http://ideone.com/xv1OHl

Comment: @PravasiMeet, no, it is not fine. What part of my answer and the comments above is not clear?

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this cause undefined behaviour?

Because the language doesn't specify how polymorphism is implemented, and therefore can't specify that polymorphic types be trivially copyable.

> I can see no logical implementation of the language where this would not behave as expected

Polymorphism could be implemented as a map from object addresses to type information, rather than a pointer stored in each object. One might debate whether that would be better or worse, but it's certainly not illogical.

> why did the language designers choose to make this undefined?

So as not to constrain the possibility of coming up with better implementations of polymorphism. Your inability to see alternatives doesn't necessarily mean that they don't exist.

Comment: AFAICT there are only 2 categories of possible implementations of polymorphism: those where the type of the object is intrinsic to the object's data, as in a vtable, or those where some external method of associating the type is used, and the object's data is interpreted only as the declared data elements. But in either case, this scenario (where both source and destination have the same type) would be guaranteed to work: if intrinsic, the object type would be copied and therefore left unchanged, while if external the mechanism would be untouched and ythe type information would be unchanged.

Comment: @jules: That may or may not be the case, but the standard didn't try to enumerate all possible implementations, or even just those you can imagine. It left the implementation up to the implementor, without constraining them to keep the class trivial. Polymorphic classes are usually non-trivial in other ways too, and you rarely want to combine byte-wrangling with high-level abstractions, so that seems entirely reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you use memcpy then you are bypassing the object's copy constructors. This leaves your program in an incoherent state (aka undefined behavior).

Comment: Yes, but it ought to be a predictable state (e.g. if you copy an object that holds a resource, that resource will be double-freed unless you take some step to prevent it).